# onclick JQuery function in HTML th tag to set datepicker value to different date(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to do this:

```
<th><a href="#" onclick="[set datepicker value to + 7 days]"> > next week </a></th>
```

I've tried this and the onclick action isn't calling.  Is there a way to change datepicker value to +7 days within a th tag within an HTML table?

Comment: What happens when you move the onclick-event to the th-element?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DateWeek").click(function () {
            var dt = new Date();
            var someDate = new Date();
            var numberOfDaysToAdd = 7;
            someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 

            $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", someDate);
        });
    });



</script>


     <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    <a id="DateWeek"> click me</a>
```